# Mysql Table creation from Mysql workbench to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi i had the following table structure on mysql workbench for a table `example_1`

But because of some reasons i want to recreate all the tables in `phpmyadmin` with the `create table sysntax` like below

**Create table code in MYSQL workbench**:

```
CREATE TABLE `example_1` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facility_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `template_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_num` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pdf_path` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `skills` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tracking_pixel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_renew` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),
  KEY `source_id_idxfk` (`source_id`),
  KEY `facility_id_idxfk` (`facility_id`),
  KEY `job_type_id_idxfk` (`job_type_id`),
  KEY `template_id_idxfk` (`template_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `jp_job_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `jp_source` (`source_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `jp_job_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`facility_id`) REFERENCES `adm_facility` (`facility_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `jp_job_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`job_type_id`) REFERENCES `jp_job_type` (`job_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `jp_job_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `jp_template` (`template_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I had copied and pasted the same in `phpmyadmin` to create the same table, then i got the following error

**Error**:

```
InnoDB  

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

[ Variables | Buffer Pool | InnoDB Status ]
```

Can anyone please let me know how to edit the code in order to avoid errors and create a table in phpmyadmin sql editor

Comment: Do the referenced tables exist?

Comment: @Lex: Thank you very much actually there are no reference tables , so i created those tables and runned the query again and it worked

Comment: Great success! Too bad for me I didn't post it as an asnswer... Glad to be of help.

Comment: Hmmm dont worry i have another question if you dont mind you can look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172768/how-to-convert-a-query-from-mssql-in-to-a-query-in-msql

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `INNODB` Engine is disabled on your server. Just remove any disable options for innodb in `/etc/my.cnf` and restart `mysql`.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply and i think inn0odb is not disabled because the same code worked when i removed the constraint lines above and a table has created, it seems the problem is with constraint statement and dont know how to solve it