# How to convert a query from Mssql in to a query in Msql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi I worked on Mssql recently and somewhere i got following query

```
query = "select dateadd(SS,1,getdate()) as 'StartTime'"
```

Here i can expect `getdate()` in Mssql is `now()` in Mysql

But i want to do the functionality of the above **MSSQL** query in **MYSQL** , so can anyone please let me know how to write the same query in MYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

`SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AS starttime`

Answer (score 2):

```
DATE_ADD(now(), 1, 'SECONDS')
```

Based on documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

OR

```
now() + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
```

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "SELECT DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) as StartTime"
```

## [See the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfab1/6)

Reference [MySQL: DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
query = "SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW, INTERVAL 1 SECOND) `Start_Time`"
```

**[DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)**